# Mongodb schema design for property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model, database

I am planning to redesign my legacy property inspection from traditional relation database to use mongodb. I am pretty new to mongodb schema design and would like your advices on how to design the schema

In legacy database I have the following tables below

Property (hold property data information)

- PropertyID
- Address
- ZipCode
- State
- Country
- Status
- Type

PropertyField (dynamic fields of property in hierarchical structure)
 - FieldID
 - FieldParentID
 - FieldName
 - FieldDescription

Example: Kitchen, Kitchen > Windows

InspectionTemplate (template for fields of the property need to be inspected)

- TemplateID
- TemplateName
  Example: Inspect Only Internal Structure

InspectionTemplateField (fields are required for inspector to fill in)

- InspectionTemplateFieldID
- TemplateID
- PropertyFieldID
- IsMandatory

Inspection (inspection info)

- InspectionID
- StartDate
- DueDate
- LastInspectionDate
- AssignedTo
- TemplateID
- Status

Condition (condition of property field)

- ConditionID
- ConditionName

Example: Good, Fair, Need-Replace ,Poor, Need-Repair

PropertyCondition (the current and previous condition of the property)

- PropertyID
- InspectionID
- ConditionID
- PropertyFieldID
- PropertyFieldOldValue (need to copy value from last inspection)
- PropertyFieldNewValue
- Picture
- Comments

My questions for mongodb schema redesign are

1. Should I used embedded or reference data model? My understanding, embedded data model is best suit for this since I need to load a single property and update the entire property relate data frequently e.g. inspector login to mobile app and select property to inspect. The system will load all property information including all property dynamic fields. However, if I used this data model, it may impact on the performance since I need to load a big chunk of data to mobile device and update info back to the server. Any better ideas for this?
2. What type of tree data model I need to use to traverse and update all of the property field information? For example, I need to update the condition of the field

```
 Exterior 
|   |_ FrontDoor
|   |_ BackDoor
|   |_ Fence
|Gargage
|   |_ Walls
|   |_ Windows
|MasterBedRooms
|   |_ Sink
|   |_ Cabinet    
|Fireplace
```

According Mongodb tree data model pattern, Materialized Paths  is best for this case because it gives best performance to query node and subnode. However , the document did not mention whether it is a good performance to update or insert to new node to tree.

Regards,
Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

**Ques 1:**

Some of the points I can think of are:

Reference Model, if:

- Embedding documents will lead the document to cross the threshold size (I guess its 16 megabytes per document).
- You don't mind fetching documents multiple times for a set of operations.

Embedded Model, if:

- Large number of operations to be done on the same document and related document
- Document size is not large

**Ques 2:**
I could not understand the question. Sorry! Try re-framing.

Comment: In question 2: I need to select each node of the tree and perform update/insert relate information. Which tree data model I need to use for this?